# Continuous marginal distributions do not imply continuous joint distribution

Tags: probability-theory, examples-counterexamples

I already proved the other implication. I need to find an explicit example that shows that if there is some random vector $(X,Y)$ and $X$ and $Y$ have both continuous marginal distributions, then distribution of ($X,Y$) is not necessarily continuous type.

Any help please?

Comment: $$X=Y{}{}{}{}$$

Comment: @Did You are too fast and my internet connection too slow. :/

Comment: @saz But I upvote good answers... :-)

Comment: In the _other_ implication that you have already proved, what exactly is meant by "continuous joint distribution"? Is it that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is a continuous function of $x$ as well as a continuous function of $y$ for all $x, y$ in the plane (which excludes, for example, $\mathbf 1_{x\colon x\in [0,1]}\mathbf 1_{y\colon y \in [0,1]}$ as a continuous joint distribution)? Or is it that the support of $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is a set of positive measure?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider $(X,Y) := (X,X)$ for a continuous random variable $X$. Show that 
$$D := \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2; x=y\}$$

has Lebesgue measure zero, but $\mathbb{P}((X,Y) \in D)=1$. Conclude that $(X,Y)$ is not absolutely continuous (with respect to the Lebesgue measure).

Comment: Could you possibly explain why we need notion of absolutely continuous measure here? Thank you!

Comment: @luka5z Well, how do you define a "continuous" random variable?

Comment: I didnt define continuous random variable, but only continuous distribution

Comment: So how do you define those?

Comment: I say that random vector $X=(X_1,\ldots, X_n)$ has continuous distribution if there exists integrable function $f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ such that for any $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, $P(B)=\int_B f(x)dx$

Comment: @luka5z I see. You can simply replace "absolutely continuous (with respect to the Lebesgue measure)" by "continuous".

Comment: Thanks, btw - very simple counterexample, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take $X$ and $Y$ as being fully correlated bivariate normal random variables.  Then the joint density is given by dirac masses as follows:
$$f(x, y) = g(x)\delta_x(y)$$
where $g(x)$ is a standard normal density.