# Proving $\large \mathrm{X}$ and $\large \mathrm{Y}$ are not jointly continuous but marginally each of them are continuous?

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, random-variables

Let $\large \mathrm {X} \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$. $\large \mathrm {(X,Y)}$ have a joint pdf . Define $\large \mathrm{Y=X}$. Then show that $\large \mathrm{X}$ and $\large \mathrm{Y}$ are not jointly continuous but even though marginally each of them is a continuous random variable.

This is how I approach to prove the problem.

[image]

> $\textrm{Define a diagonal } \mathrm{L} \textrm{ joining the points O and B.}  \\\ \large \mathrm{X} , \large \mathrm{Y} \underset{cont} \sim \mathcal{U}(0,1) \\\   \large \mathrm{X} = \large \mathrm{Y} \normalsize \textrm { with probability } 1 \\\ \large \mathrm{L} \normalsize \textrm{ is an } 1- \normalsize \textrm{dimensional set} \\\ \\\ \textbf{Observation :- } \\\ \\\ \textrm{The projection of the diagonal line } \mathrm{L} \textrm{ both on the X and Y-axis yield a set of singletons }  \\\   \textrm { Hence by the theory of integration we are going to integrate a two-dimensional function on} \\\ \textrm{ a one-dimensional set, therefore } \large \mathbb{P}[(\mathrm{X, Y}) \in \mathrm{L}] \normalsize \textrm{ should be } 0 \\\ \textrm{Also } \large \mathbb{P}[(\mathrm{X, Y}) \in \mathrm{L}] \\\ = \large \underset{L} {\int \int} \mathrm{f_{_{X,Y}}{(x,y)} } dx dy   \\\ = \large \underset{L} {\int \int} \mathrm{f_{_{X,Y}}{(x,y)} } dy dx \normalsize \textrm{ by Fubini's theorem} \\\ = \large \underset{L} {\int \int} 1 \ dy dx = 1    \\\ \textrm{Here } \large \mathrm{OABC} \normalsize \textrm{ is a unit square and the diagonal line } \large \mathrm{L} \normalsize \textrm{ joining the points } \large \mathrm{O} \normalsize \textrm{ and } \large \mathrm{B} \normalsize \textrm{ divides } \\\  \textrm{the total are of the unit square into the areas of two congruent triangles } \triangle \textrm{OBA and } \triangle \textrm{OBC} \\\ \therefore \textrm{Area of } \triangle \textrm{OBA} = \textrm{Area of } \triangle \textrm{OBC} \\\ \textrm{Also, area of the diagonal line } \large \mathrm{L}= \normalsize \textrm{Area of } \large \triangle \textrm{OBA} - \normalsize \textrm{Area of } \large \triangle \textrm{OBC} \\\ \Longrightarrow \large \mathbb{P}[(\mathrm{X, Y}) \in \mathrm{L}]= \large \mathbb{P}[(\mathrm{X, Y}) \in \triangle \normalsize \textrm{OBA}] - \large \mathbb{P}[(\mathrm{X, Y}) \in \triangle \normalsize \textrm{OBC}] \\\ \Longrightarrow \large \mathbb{P}[(\mathrm{X, X}) \in \mathrm{L}]= \large \mathbb{P}[(\mathrm{X, X}) \in \triangle \normalsize \textrm{OBA}] - \large \mathbb{P}[(\mathrm{X, X}) \in \triangle \normalsize \textrm{OBC}] \normalsize \textrm{ , since } \large \mathrm{X=Y} \normalsize \textrm{ with probability } 1 \\\ \Longrightarrow \large \mathbb{P}[\mathrm{X} \in \mathrm{L}]= \large \mathbb{P}[\mathrm{X} \in \triangle \normalsize \textrm{OBA}] - \large \mathbb{P}[\mathrm{X} \in \triangle \normalsize \textrm{OBC}] = \large \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} =0 \\\ \textrm{Therefore jointly } \large \mathrm{X,Y} \normalsize \textrm{ are degenerate and not continuous } \\\ \textrm{ but marginally each of them are continuous random variable.}$

• Is this proof correct? If it is or it isn't could you please kindly provide a correct (or an alternative proof) in this problem?

• Also can we prove the same by directly stating that the joint PDF $\large \mathrm{f_{X,Y}(x, y)}$ is $0$ for almost all points in the unit square except on the line $\mathrm{y = x}$? Since the integral needs to be evaluated over the entire region $\mathrm{L}$, and the function is $0$ almost everywhere on $\mathrm{L}$, the integral wouldn't converge to a finite value, violating the definition of joint continuity.

Also I understand what [Saz's proof want to say in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1360793/continuous-marginal-distributions-do-not-imply-continuous-joint-distribution) yet I am not sure whether I have implied that correctly in my proof.

Hence, any help is valuable and appreciated.

Comment: There are two non-equivalent definitions of a continuous random variable. If you mean existence of density then the easiest proof is to say that $f_{X,Y}=0$ a.e..

Comment: Yes, I mean $(X,Y)$ have a joint density and the joint density exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this proof is not correct.  I don't know exactly what you mean by "The projection of the diagonal line L both on the X and Y-axis yield a set of singletons," but any way to describe projection I know of would have the projection of $L$ onto either axis be $[0,1]$ rather than a set of singletons.

Next, you say $\mathbb{P}((X,Y) \in L) = 0$, but in reality $$\mathbb{P}((X,Y) \in L) = \mathbb{P}((X,X) \in L) = \mathbb{P}(X \in [0,1]) = 1.$$

You reference the function $f_{X,Y}$ without defining it, and during the subsequent calculation apply Fubini's theorem for seemingly no reason.  In the end, you conclude $\iint_L f_{X,Y}(x,y) dydx = 1,$ but since $L$ has Lebesgue measure $0$, the integral of any function over it is $0$.

Near the end, you write $\mathbb{P}(X \in L)$, which is nonsense.  $X \sim U(0,1)$, so $X$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}$ and hence cannot be part of any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  You then claim $\mathbb{P}(X \in \triangle OBA) = \frac 12$, but again, $X$ cannot be in any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

The easiest proof would be to observe that $L$ has Lebesgue measure $0$, but $\mathbb{P}((X,Y) \in L) = 1$, so the joint distribution function cannot be absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, i.e. the joint pdf does not exist.

Comment: +1 For the answer and pointing out my errors in my proof. I understand your last paragraph but my target was to write a non-measure theoretic proof which I failed. Thank you again for your answer.

Comment: @TopoSet32 I don't know how one can define what it means to be "jointly continuous" without at least some measure theory.